# JavaScript showing previously on clicked data

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am showing data using modal. In the modal I am showing data dynamically that are fetching from database. For back-end I am using Laravel. For showing data to the modal dynamically I have created a function in the button where on clicking modal is opening. Here is the button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="sendData('{!!$singleWorkout->title!!}', '{!!$singleWorkout->image!!}')">View</button>
```

Here I am sending dynamic data to the `sendData` function. 
Here is my `sendData` function code.

```
function sendData(title, image) {
$('#modal-title').append(title);
$('#modal-image').append('<img src="/file/'+image+'" height="200px" width="100%">');
}
```

This function appending data to my modal dynamically.

Here is my modal code.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">
        <div id="modal-title">

        </div>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-image">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now the problem is, if I click on the `view` button for opening modal its worked fine for the first click. If I click on the button again then it shows newly clicked data also shows previously clicked data. So my question is how I can stop showing that previously clicked data.

Answer (score 0):

And finally I have fount the solution. I have used `html` instead of `append`. So my js function is looks like

```
function sendData(title, image) {
$('#modal-title').html(title);
$('#modal-image').html('<img src="/file/'+image+'" height="200px" width="100%">');
```

}